# How to determine if a type is derived from a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11, type-traits

How can I determine if a type is derived from a template class?  In particular, I need to determine if a template parameter has `std::basic_ostream` as a base class.  Normally `std::is_base_of` is the tool for the job.  However, `std::is_base_of` only works for complete types not class templates.

I'm looking for something like this.

```
template< typename T >
bool is_based_in_basic_ostream( T&& t )
{
   if( std::is_base_of< std::basic_ostream< /*anything*/>, T >::value )
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I'm sure this can be done I can't think how.

Comment: Just want to throw in... you can replace that entire if/else branch with just a single `return` line that returns the condition in the if statement!

Comment: is `typename T` a complete type ? What would you specify as `/* anything */` in your code ?

Comment: In my situation I'd only expect to see the integral character types there.  I believe the basic_ostream cannot be instantiated unless `/*anything*/` is a complete type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not aware of a short and concise way. But you can abuse overloading again

```
template< typename T, typename U >
std::true_type is_based_impl( std::basic_ostream<T, U> const volatile& );
std::false_type is_based_impl( ... );

template< typename T >
bool is_based_in_basic_ostream( T&& t ) {
  return decltype(is_based_impl(t))::value;
}
```

It will only detect public inheritance. Note that you can instead detect derivation from `ios_base`, which may work for you equally well (this test will also be positive for input streams, so it's only of limited applicability)

```
std::is_base_of<std::ios_base, T>
```

Comment: The problem with checking for `std::ios_base` is that it would detect input streams as well, which may violate the semantics the OP desires.

Comment: @ildjarn I agree. I think I should have been more clearer. Thanks for noting that explicitly. Fixed :)

Comment: Is there a concrete reason why you're using `const volatile&`, and not just `const&`?

Answer (score 5):

Might something like Boost's is_instance_of be what you are after?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/lambda/detail/is_instance_of.hpp

Here is the short version for 1-argument templates:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename> class F>
struct conversion_tester
{
        template <typename T>
        conversion_tester (const F<T> &);
};

template <class From, template <typename> class To>
struct is_instance_of
{
        static const bool value = std::is_convertible<From,conversion_tester<To>>::value;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename T>
struct bar {};

int main()
{
        std::cout << is_instance_of<foo<int>,foo>::value << '\n'; // This will print '1'.
        std::cout << is_instance_of<bar<int>,foo>::value << '\n'; // This will print '0'.
}
```

Unfortunately, if you try to extend this to variadic templates, with current GCC (4.6.0) it will produce an error message. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749863/variadic-templates-and-copy-construction-via-assignment) implies that this is currently a problem of GCC and that the variadic template version is supposed to work according to the standard.