# How to determine if a type is derived from a template class at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

Say I have some template classes:

```
template<class T>
class Foo{}

template<class T>
class Bar{}
```

Now, I want to make sure (at compile-time) that the type used in `Bar` is derived from `Foo`. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997956/how-to-determine-if-a-type-is-derived-from-a-template-class) answer that shows how to do it at runtime, but I would like to check at compile-time, maybe using `static_assert` or something.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There might be some [type-traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types#Type_traits_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29) you could use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, I looked into that a bit. is_base_of might work, but I only know how to use it when Foo is a normal class and not a template class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now, I want to make sure (at compiletime) that the type used in Bar is derived from Foo.

You can do something like this:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<class T>
class Foo{};

template<typename T>
std::true_type test(const Foo<T> &);

std::false_type test(...);

template<class T>
class Bar {
    static_assert(decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value, "!");
};

struct S: Foo<int> {};

int main() {
    Bar<S> ok1;
    Bar<Foo<int>> ok2;
    // Bar<int> ko;
}
```

See it on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JmtPGNdb93CL4ZwL).
The basic idea is that you can bind a temporary of type `T` to `const Foo<U> &` if `T` is derived from a specialization of `Foo`, no matter what's `U`. Therefore you can declare (no definition required) a couple of functions like the ones in the example to test it, then use the declared return type in a `static_assert` or any other constant context.

---

**Edit**

As suggested by @Quentin in the comments, probably it's worth replacing the reference with a pointer to prevent false positives from conversion constructors and operators.

Comment: This checks for exactly Foo, OP want subtype of Foo.

Comment: @yurikilochek Right. Fixed to match derived classes.

Comment: I'd replace the reference with a pointer to prevent false positives from conversion constructors and operators.

Comment: @Quentin Good point. Anyway I should be able to take the address of what's returned by `std::declval` to do that and I don't think there is a way. Am I wrong?

Comment: @skypjack `std::declval<T*>()` ? ;)

Comment: @Quentin Ahahah. Fair enough. Your point. ;-) ... Can I copy your comment above (with credits) into the question?